# How to replace &apos; or any special character in when using XMLELEMENT Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, replace, xmlelement

I have the below query. How to keep the apostrophe (`'`) intact and not getting it replaced by `&apos`
There are other characters also I want to handle like `&`

```
SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,'I''m'||':')).EXTRACT('//text()'),':')
  FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
I&apos;m
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can make use of [utl_i18n](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_i18n.htm) package and [unescape_reference()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_i18n.htm#i998992) function in particular. Here is an example:

```
clear screen;
column res format a7;

select utl_i18n.unescape_reference(
          rtrim(
               xmlagg( -- use of xmlagg() function in 
                       -- this situation seems to be unnecessary 
                       XMLELEMENT(E,'I''m'||':')
                      ).extract('//text()'),':'
                )
        ) as res
 from dual;
```

Result:

```
RES   
-------
I'm
```

Comment: This one have a limitation on 4000 characters

Comment: @Skoffer Yes it has. To overcome this limitation the `dbms_xmlgen` package and specifically `convert()` function [can be used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683423/is-oracles-extract-function-breaking-the-noentityescaping-in-the-xmlelement/23684068#23684068)

Comment: That helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT dbms_xmlgen.convert( xmlagg(XMLELEMENT(E,'I''m'
  ||':')).extract('//text()').getclobval() ,1)
FROM dual;
```

---

I'm:

Comment: Thanks a lot! its a nice one too, but its getting the output in HUGECLOB