# Is Oracle's EXTRACT function breaking the NOENTITYESCAPING in the XMLELEMENT?

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, escaping, extract

Oracle 11g. I figured out that if I add `NOENTITYESCAPING` to the `XMLELEMENT` function, it nicely turns off entity escaping. However, when I then pass the result to `EXTRACT` the escaping seems to come back again.

```
select xmlelement(NOENTITYESCAPING e,id,'->') 
  from (select level as id 
          from dual 
       connect by level < 6)      

XMLELEMENT(NOENTITYESCAPINGE,ID,'->')
---------------------------------------
<E>1-></E>
<E>2-></E>
<E>3-></E>
<E>4-></E>
<E>5-></E>
```

Now, adding `EXTRACT`:

```
select xmlelement(NOENTITYESCAPING e,id,'->').extract('//text()')
  from (select level as id 
          from dual 
       connect by level < 6)

XMLELEMENT(NOENTITYESCAPINGE,ID,'->').EXTRACT('//TEXT()')
----------------------------------------------------------
1-&gt;
2-&gt;
3-&gt;
4-&gt;
5-&gt;
```

Any fixes/workarounds to keep the escaping switched off? The [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions053.htm#SQLRF00640) gives no help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use `extractvalue()` function, which unescapes encoded entities, instead of `extract()`. Here is an example:

```
clear screen;
column res format a20;

-- depending on a situation, NOENTITYESCAPING might be dropped

select extractvalue(
                     xmlelement(NOENTITYESCAPING e,id,'->')
                    , '//text()'
                    ) as res
  from (select level as id 
          from dual 
       connect by level < 6)
```

Result:

```
RES                
--------------------
1->                  
2->                  
3->                  
4->                  
5->
```

But the use of `extractvalue()` function may be limited by the fact that it can return value of only one node. In a case of returning values of multiple nodes the `utl_i18n` package, and `unescape_reference()` function of that package can be used to unescape encoded entities:

```
clear screen;
column res format a20;

select utl_i18n.unescape_reference(xmlelement(root
                                             , xmlelement(node1, '>')
                                             , xmlelement(node2, '<')
                                             ).extract('//text()').getstringval()
                                   ) as res
 from dual
connect by level <= 3;
```

Result:

```
RES                
--------------------
><                   
><                   
><
```

---

Yes, as `utl_i18n.unescape_reference()` function accepts only values of `varchar2` data type and types that can be implicitly converted to the `varchar2` data type, your hands are tied when it comes to processing large "*strings*". In this situation you may turn to `dbms_xmlgen` package and [convert()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_xmlgen.htm#ARPLS69852) function in particular, which has an overloaded version capable of accepting `CLOB`s. Here is an example:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.convert(
                           xmlagg(xmlelement(root
                                             , xmlelement(node1, '>')
                                             , xmlelement(node2, '<')
                                             )
                                  ).extract('//text()').getclobval()
                          , 1) as res
 from dual
connect by level <= 3000;   -- 1 (second parameter of the convert() function)
                            -- instructs function to decode entities
```

Result:

```
RES
------------------------------------------------------
><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
-- ... the rest of the CLOB
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. I see you updated your answer as I was just about to comment that as I'm using XMLAGG (to work around LISTAGG's 4000 char limit), and that extractvalue won't work with that. I've tried your recommendation of utl_i18n.unescape_reference, however I think that's hitting the 4000 char limit too.

Comment: Here's my current query, which demonstrates the problem: select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement( e,id,'->').extract('//text()') order by id).GetClobVal(),',')
from (select level as id from dual connect by level < 6)

Comment: @TrojanName `I think that's hitting the 4000 char limit too` Yes. `unescape_reference()` function accepts `varchar2` values. To process "*big*" strings use `dbms_xmlgen.convert()` function. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Wow, phenomenal answer! Thank you so much. Oracle has so many ways of doing things, probably too many at times. :-)

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful to me and saved me using the undocumented NOENTITYESCAPING. XML in oracle really is a big topic!