# How to remove ELEMENTs from XMLELEMENT in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, nsxmlelement

I am trying to get rid of few changes while using XMLELEMENT.
Below is an example:

```
SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, ' ---- test using & (Ampersand) and '' (Apostrophe) ---- ')).EXTRACT('//text()').GETCLOBVAL() FROM DUAL;
```

It produces a `HUGECLOB`:

-- test using `&amp`; (Ampersand) and `&apos`; (Apostrophe) --

But I need the `exact content`:

-- test using & (Ampersand) and ' (Apostrophe) --

In `XMLELEMENT` its mandatory to pass Element Name (any character or string)

Is there any other option ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found related answer:

[How to replace &apos; or any special character in when using XMLELEMENT Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369574/how-to-replace-apos-or-any-special-character-in-when-using-xmlelement-oracle)

Use of utl_i18n.unescape_reference

If you have anymore better option please reply.
Thanks